# jQuery - response of ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Studying the following ajax request, I was wondering:

- What advantages can a non-async ajax call  achieve?
- What is the `.responseMessage` good for, what does it store?

  ```
   var myTemplate = $.ajax({

          type: "GET",
          url: "myurl.html",
          async: false,
          cache: false

  }).responseMessage;
  ```

Comment: 1. https://www.google.com/search?q=What+advantages+can+a+non-async+ajax+call+achieve%3F, 2. well the _response_ of the AJAX call supposedly …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting **async** to **false** means that the statement you are calling has to complete before the next statement in your function can be called. If you set async: true then that statement will begin it's execution and the next statement will be called regardless of whether the async statement has completed yet.

In your code the function will not continue execution until the ajax call is complete.